# How could i read multiple PDF files from folder in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
This is my Upload Button Code. I want to upload pdf file and then read all the files that is uploaded. 


 protected void Upload_Files(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (fileUpload.HasFile)     // CHECK IF ANY FILE HAS BEEN SELECTED.
                {
                    int iUploadedCnt = 0;
                    int iFailedCnt = 0;
                    HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
                    lblFileList.Text = "Select <b>" + hfc.Count + "</b> file(s)";

                    if (hfc.Count <= 10)    // 10 FILES RESTRICTION.
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= hfc.Count - 1; i++)
                        {
                            HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                            if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                            {
                                if (!File.Exists(Server.MapPath("CopyFiles\\") +Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)))
                                {
                                    DirectoryInfo objDir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("CopyFiles\\"));

                                    string sFileName = Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                                    string sFileExt = Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName);

                                    // CHECK FOR DUPLICATE FILES.
                                    FileInfo[] objFI = objDir.GetFiles(sFileName.Replace(sFileExt, "") + "*.pdf");

                                    if (objFI.Length > 0)
                                    {
                                        // CHECK IF FILE WITH THE SAME NAME EXISTS 

                                        foreach (FileInfo file in objFI)
                                        {
                                            string sFileName1 = objFI[0].Name;
                                            string sFileExt1 = Path.GetExtension(objFI[0].Name);

                                            if (sFileName1.Replace(sFileExt1, "") == sFileName.Replace(sFileExt, ""))
                                            {
                                                iFailedCnt += 1;        // NOT ALLOWING DUPLICATE.
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        // SAVE THE FILE IN A FOLDER.
                                        hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("CopyFiles\\") + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                                        iUploadedCnt += 1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        lblUploadStatus.Text = "<b>" + iUploadedCnt + "</b> file(s) Uploaded.";
                        lblFailedStatus.Text = "<b>" + iFailedCnt + "</b> duplicate file(s) could not be uploaded.";
                    }
                    else lblUploadStatus.Text = "Max. 10 files allowed.";
                }
                else lblUploadStatus.Text = "No files selected.";



            }
```

**I am facing error in Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName**) in my this method when i m using library using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser; in my code. i am using Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName) to upload files from browser.

```
                          if (!File.Exists(Server.MapPath("CopyFiles\\") +Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)))
                            {
                                DirectoryInfo objDir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("CopyFiles\\"));

                                string sFileName = Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                                string sFileExt = Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName);

                                // CHECK FOR DUPLICATE FILES.
                                FileInfo[] objFI = objDir.GetFiles(sFileName.Replace(sFileExt, "") + "*.pdf");

                                if (objFI.Length > 0)
                                {
                                    // CHECK IF FILE WITH THE SAME NAME EXISTS 

                                    foreach (FileInfo file in objFI)
                                    {
                                        string sFileName1 = objFI[0].Name;
                                        string sFileExt1 = Path.GetExtension(objFI[0].Name);

                                        if (sFileName1.Replace(sFileExt1, "") == sFileName.Replace(sFileExt, ""))
                                        {
                                            iFailedCnt += 1;        // NOT ALLOWING DUPLICATE.
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // SAVE THE FILE IN A FOLDER.
                                    hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("CopyFiles\\") + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                                    iUploadedCnt += 1;
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: Please correct the code formatting in your question. Also "I'm facing some issues" does not tell us anything. What is not working? What is supposed to happen and what is actually happening? Is there an error, what is the error message?

Comment: Did you have a stacktrace, if yes, post it please

Comment: No, I don't have Stack Trace. @Jimbot